# Filtering users with a range of letters

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to search for all users with Names that start with a range of letters (for example A-E). Based on the research I've done this should work.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '[a-e]*'"
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Apologies; I'm getting no results. When filtering without a range of letters it works.

Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'a*'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter syntax lets you use Powershell operators and arguments to create LDAP queries, but you're still limited to the capabilites of LDAP.  I don't believe that will work because there's no analog to blobbing in LDAP queries to translate it to.  This does seem to work:

```
get-aduser -filter {(name -gt 'a') -and (name -lt 'f')}
```